# rdlc report in space

Tags: c#, wpf, oledb, rdlc

I am using access (oledb) database in WPF Application and I am developing RDLC report. And I have some problems.

I have a text datatype for this data IN20102029382818. It is 16 character. And I would like to show 10 character in 1 line, 6 character in 2 line and put some space between these characters. I would like to show this data like below.

```
I N 2 0 1 0 2 0 2 9 
3 8 2 8 1 8
```

Here, I am using textbox for showing these data on RDLC report. If I can get desire result then I can use anything for this result. I have this data from the access database but I don't know about any method for doing this things.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using `RDLC Expression` that you can use only with strings of 16 character:

```
=Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 1, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 2, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 3, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 4, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 5, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 6, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 7, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 8, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 9, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Left(Fields!YourField.Value, 10), 10, 1) +
System.Environment.NewLine +
Mid(Right(Fields!YourField.Value, 6), 1, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Right(Fields!YourField.Value, 6), 2, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Right(Fields!YourField.Value, 6), 3, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Right(Fields!YourField.Value, 6), 4, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Right(Fields!YourField.Value, 6), 5, 1) +
Space(1) +
Mid(Right(Fields!YourField.Value, 6), 6, 1)
```

This is a cleaner solution using `VB.NET`; you can translate it in `C#` and use it on your `ReportDataSource` before passing data to `ReportViewer`.

```
Dim strYourString As String = "IN20102029382818"

Dim strYourStringFormatted As String = String.Join(Space(1), Array.ConvertAll(Strings.Left(strYourString, 10).ToCharArray, Function(strInput) strInput.ToString)) _
    & System.Environment.NewLine _
    & String.Join(Space(1), Array.ConvertAll(Strings.Right(strYourString, 6).ToCharArray, Function(strInput) strInput.ToString))

MsgBox(strYourStringFormatted)
```

You can also use a variant of the second solution for any other strings; i.e.:

```
Dim strYourString As String = "Test1 Test2 Test3"

Dim strYourStringFormatted As String = Strings.Replace( _
    String.Join(Space(1), Array.ConvertAll(strYourString.ToCharArray, Function(strInput) strInput.ToString)), _
    Space(3), System.Environment.NewLine)

MsgBox(strYourStringFormatted)
```

Comment: I have one more question please help me out in it. Now, I have one column FIRSTNAME. And same way i would like to print firstname data on report file. I try this way but i got below error :-                                   The Value expression for the textrun ‘FirstName.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.                                                                                    I think that i got this error because firstname character is not fixed.

Comment: i know about this method bro.

Comment: answer updated with alternative solutions in VB.NET; maybe they can also resolve your FIRSTNAME column problem.

Comment: here, i have problem. I have NAME column and I would like to print it same way. But it's length is not fix. So how can I do it ?   I would like to print 15 character in one line and 18 character in second line. Please help me out. I try it as you give me first solution but it was not perfect. Some character repeat in second line that's the problem.